# How to seed data from AJAX response when Datatables is already initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a mix of Select2JS and Datatables and here is the code involved in the issue:

```
$(function() {
    var form_id = $('#form_id'),
        form_results = $('#form_results');

    form_results.DataTable();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'json',
        url: '/ajax/forms/get/',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            form_id: null,
            show_archived: !!$('#show_archived').is(':checked'),
            get_first: false,
            format: 'select2',
        }),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            form_id.removeAttr('disabled');
            form_id.select2({
                data: data,
                closeOnSelect: true,
                matcher,
                sorter,
            }).on('select2:select', function(e) {
                var selected_element = $(e.currentTarget);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'json',
                    url: '/ajax/manage_forms/getFormData/',
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        form_id: selected_element.val(),
                        get_first: true,
                    }),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        form_results.DataTable({
                            data: response.data,
                            retrieve: true,
                            stateSave: true,
                            responsive: true,
                            columnDefs: [
                                {
                                    className: 'select-checkbox',
                                    orderable: false,
                                    searchable: false,
                                    targets: 0,
                                },
                            ],
                            select: {
                                style: 'multiple',
                                selector: 'td:first-child',
                            },
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console.error(xhr.responseText);
                    },
                });
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.error(xhr.responseText);
        },
    });
});
```

On the PHP side there is a function building the data and send it back to the browser:

```php
public function getFormData()
{
    $inputJSON  = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $outputJSON = json_decode($inputJSON, true);
    $arguments  = array(
        'Id'           => $outputJSON['form_id'],
        'FormName'     => null,
        'FormFileName' => null,
        'FormTypeId'   => 1
    );

    $form = $this->forms_model->get($arguments, $outputJSON['get_first'], self::$folders);

    $result[] = array(
        '',
        'DT_RowId' => $form->Id,
        $form->FormName,
        $form->FaxNumber,
        end(explode('/', $form->form_filepath))
    );

    return $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(array('data' => $result)));
}
```

The result from the above function looks like:

```
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "0" : "",
            "DT_RowId" : 3387,
            "1" : "form",
            "2" : "8772399284",
            "3" : "form1.pdf"
        }
    ]
}
```

For some reason the table is showing all the time "No data available in table" and I can't find where is the issue, can any find out what is wrong in my code?

I have spent the last two hours trying to figure this out but I can't.

**Updates:**

@charlietfl: the following didn't work at first complaining about the `k` not being defined so I modified a little bit however it didn't do the trick

```
response.data.map(function(k, o) {
    return Object.keys(k).map(function(k) { return o[k];});
});
```

@CFP Support: your solution is not working either for some reason the table doesn't get updated with data.

In both cases I am not getting any Javascript error or nothing weird in the console it just does not work.

Comment: You haven't told datatables what object key goes in which column

Comment: @charlietfl Do I need to define them? I didn't know it though I am not sure in how to define them when the index is numeric, can you give me some example?

Comment: Although numeric they are still strings. Object keys are always string

Comment: Or you could flatten data to array of arrays also. `data:response.data.map(function(o){ return Object.keys(k).map(function(k){ return o[k]})})`. So long as headings length in table matches inner array length it should populate

Comment: @charlietfl check my updates!

Comment: Try not initializing the plugin before the ajax and make sure number of `<th>` columns matches

Comment: works fine for me - updated my answer with jsfiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/CFPSupport/5utwh4v3/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "columns" and define them.

```
  ...stuff...
    columnDefs: [
         {
           className: 'select-checkbox',
           orderable: false,
          searchable: false,
             targets: 0,
         },
      ],
      columns: [
           {data: "0"},
           {data: "DT_RowId"},
           {data: "1"},
           {data: "2"},
           {data: "3"}
      ], ....etc...
```

This tells the table what column to match with the incoming data (so you will need a table with 5 columns in the HTML - or build it with JS {not sure what you are using, but if you need help...}

This should get you past the immediate issue though.

EDIT: JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/CFPSupport/5utwh4v3/6/

EDIT2: I see the issue - you are initializing then wanting to put more data.... OK.....

You should get the data IN the datatable init, not init+AJAX.... https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax